# How can I write an iOS application that displays mail from my GMail account?

Tags: iphone, ios4

How can I write an iOS application that displays mail from my GMail account?

Comment: You need to write an imap client. Start from there.

Comment: thanks, can u provide me any sample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [libetpan](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libetpan/). It's a library for a mail client. And gmail uses IMAP, so you can use the IMAP part of libetpan.

Comment: Actually, i am using stackoverflow rarely, so..!   If possible plz provide me sample.  Thanks for reply

Comment: IMAP is not the easiest protocol. A sample that fetches mails from an account is not a sample anymore, it takes some hundred lines of code. The documentation of libetpan is not the best, but when you use the [IMAP rfc](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3501.html) next to the source code of libetpan you will get an idea. Then there is [etPanKit](https://libetpan.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/libetpan/etPanKit/trunk/) which might be good enough for you, so you don't have to touch the inner parts of libetpan at all.