# How can I read & render the email inbox of an email account in my iOS app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, email, imap

How can I read & render the email inbox of an email account (IMAP or of iOS Mail app) in my iOS app?

- I want to list the current email subjects & time of receipt.
- I want to access an IMAP account or even better the email in the iOS Mail
  app.

I know MFMailComposeViewController, but this only creates emails. I have read on libetpan and etPanKit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959546/how-can-i-write-an-ios-application-that-displays-mail-from-my-gmail-account).

Is there a library / example code / open source project doing that or something similar? Including the rendering of an inbox, some settings (account name, password, ...) in a settings bundle, etc.

I see quite some complexity and it would be great to not re-invent the wheel on that.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to gain access to the the iOS Mail App data.

You'll have to access the mail server directly using something like [Mailcore](https://github.com/mronge/MailCore).

Comment: How does MailCore relate to libetpan? Which is better (quality, support for different mail account flavours) - What is your experience?

Comment: I don't have any experience with either of them. Mailcore is the one I hear about the most.

Comment: MailCore/MailCore2 are Obj-C/C++ wrappers around libetpan.  libetpan is the low-level C framework that is doing the work either way.  MailCore/MailCore2 are easier to use and have lots of convenience functions.